# Are there any details available about the "password protection" in Apple's office suite (e.g. Numbers.app, etc.)?

Tags: password, iwork

I had a co-worker ask me if password-protecting a Numbers document was "safe" because we know that early-model MS Office versions had useless encryption and also "Zip 2.0" encryption is also not reliable. We typically use MS Office XML or AES-256 ZIP for things that need to be e.g. emailed securely.

I couldn't find much information about Numbers.app, other than the old iWork suite was discovered to be broken ~2017 (or possibly as early as 2012) and the system was re-worked at the time to use AES-128 encryption.

This is the most information I've been able to find about this online, but most us it is (fairly well-informed) speculation:
https://www.podfeet.com/blog/2019/09/iwork-password-protected/

Are there any information available about the protection modern iWork provides for its documents?

Comment: Apple is pretty closed-mouthed about its security methods and protocols. If you use a sufficiently complex password with AES128 or AES256 encryption, the ability of a brute force decryption attack actually working is astronomically small. You can always use Disk Utility to create an AES256 encrypted disk image containing the Numbers file (itself encrypted) and go with a suspenders and belt scenario. In addition, you can use the encrypted disk image to contain multiple files. Before the advent of shared items in LastPass, I used this method to store and transmit secure credentials.